# ASCII art generator with OCR

Tags: software-recommendation, ocr, ascii

What program can turn an image into ASCII-art, but also replace any text with the actual text with OCR. For example, for converting a comic to ASCII art.

Comment: Nothing I've seen thus far, but it would be an excellent c coding project to consider with libcaca. If it was done properly, with C, it would dramatically improve SDL -> libcaca -> ncurses output.

Answer (score -1):

ASCII art generators:

- [aa3d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/aa3d.1.html)
- [AA-project](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/)
- [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca)
- [GIMP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/)

For OCR there are many options, depending on the goals, but not something that will directly output ASCII-art. In any case check out the [OCR page at the Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR).